# How do i add a branding to a splash screen for ANDROID 12 when creating a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, yaml, android-12, flutter-android, android-splashscreen

I have been able to easily create a branding for lower versions of android but android 12 doesn't support branding. I wonder if there is a work around with a yaml file like how Meta was able to create a branding in all their apps(WhatsApp, Instagram, Facebook) though they used React Native.

Adding the directory to the branding component of my flutter_native_splash.yaml file creates a branding logo for android 11 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

The flutter_native_splash includes support for branding as well, but you have to set it up specifically in the `android_12` section of the `yaml` config.